# add property and value to existing class c#

Tags: c#

I have a requirement to add a property in existing class as per user configuration, I  mean if the user has been configured in the database to add a new property like property Name is 'Name', the datatype is 'string' and value is 'Mishra'.
After achieving this, I will save a list of TestClass data in Redis cache.

```
  class TestClass
    {
        public long ID { get; set; }
    }
```

I have tried from the link **https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2sd82fz7.aspx**
but I want to add an existing class, so can anyone please help me to achieve the same.

I want to render JSON data as per user property (column) configuration for my devex grid.

Data Like-

```
{
"testClass": [
    {
      "scheduledTime": "2018-07-30T15:30:00",
      "estimatedTime": "2018-07-30T15:30:00",
      "flightNumber": "EY4512",
      "airLine": "assets/images/EY_88x45.jpg",
      "fromVia": "Chengdu,Dallas",
      "partner": "EY2356",
      "status": "Departed",
      "flightColor": null,
      "cityColor": null,
      "publicArrivalPlaceholder1": "CTU,DFW",
      "publicArrivalPlaceholder2": "12_IT",
      "publicArrivalPlaceholder3": "AIR",
      "publicArrivalPlaceholder4": "7/30/2018 3:30:00 PM",
      "publicArrivalPlaceholder5": "7/30/2018 3:30:00 PM",
      "id": "179490",
      "cellRule": "",
      "rowRule": ""
    },
    {
      "scheduledTime": "2018-07-30T17:00:00",
      "estimatedTime": "2018-07-30T14:00:00",
      "flightNumber": "EY1213",
      "airLine": "assets/images/EY_88x45.jpg",
      "fromVia": "Adelaide,Ahmedabad",
      "partner": "EY8562",
      "status": "Departed",
      "flightColor": null,
      "cityColor": null,
      "publicArrivalPlaceholder1": "ADE,AMD",
      "publicArrivalPlaceholder2": "2A_T4",
      "publicArrivalPlaceholder3": "AIR",
      "publicArrivalPlaceholder4": "7/30/2018 5:00:00 PM",
      "publicArrivalPlaceholder5": "7/30/2018 2:00:00 PM",
      "id": "179489",
      "cellRule": "",
      "rowRule": ""
    }]
}
```

Here scheduledTime, estimatedTime, flightNumber etc are property that i need to resolve at run-time.

Comment: Do you want to add the property at runtime or at compile time?

Comment: What is your main purpose, are you sure a Dictionary<string, object>  will not be enough, or may be dynamic property ?

Comment: Is there a reason not to use an array with name/value pairs? Or a dictionary? Or even just have the properties default at null and only add that bit of data to the cache if it's not null?
You could also just subclass and use a function that determines which type of object to create based on given values.

Comment: I wan to add property at runtime. my main purpose is render a list type json data for my devex grid. I will get that data from a xml to mapped property from user.

Comment: [How to ignore json fields conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34304738/how-to-ignoring-fields-and-properties-conditionally-during-serialization-using-j)

Comment: How about create the same json pattern dynamically  as string and then convert to json with something like this JObject json = JObject.Parse(str); ? you can find more info at https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm

Comment: I also think this is best way to achieve the same in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you cannot change the class definition in C#. But there are some solutions:

1. Use a custom properties named for example `Fields` that will be a `Dictionary` and to add property add it to that dictionary; Or simply instead class use dictionary. Then you when you want to get class properties you just need to iterate over that dictionary.
2. Create a class in runtime and compile it dynamically; This option is more complex, and you may prefer another options - but it enabled. For more information how to compile class dynamically, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862226/how-to-dynamically-create-a-class-in-c). Then you can get a `Type` object of the class and iterate over its properties (There is the place of `TypeBuilder.DefineProperty()`; It define a new property to class that created in runtime).
3. Basically this option is like option 1, but if you're using C# 4+, you can use the keyword `dynamic`, that can be used for accessing dictionary like an object; For example, create the following class:

```
dynamic dict = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
dict.Property = "Value";
dict.Num = 123;
Console.WriteLine(dict.Property);
Console.WriteLine(dict.NonExistProperty); // Will throw an exception
```

For more information about dynamic object in C#, see [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/dynamic).

#### Edit:

Note that dynamic objects handled by DLR (Dynamic Language Runtime) and not by CLR (Common Language Runtime), and so code that use them is less effecient.