# Skip empty collections when serializing to JSON

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am working on a C# project. The following is my JSON. I want to remove the  "items":[] from it for "Type":"Product" as it is causing problems on the UI. I tried to exclude the value while JSON is being created by using the following Item class as described at [How to Ignoring Fields and Properties Conditionally During Serialization Using JSON.Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34304738/how-to-ignoring-fields-and-properties-conditionally-during-serialization-using-j). But it didn't work, not sure why. Alternatively, is there a way to remove it after the JSON is created?

```
  [
     {
      "Type":"Category",
      "Order":1,
      "id":"24",
      "text":"abc",
      "items":[
         {
            "Type":"Product",
            "Order":0,
            "id":1900,
            "text":"abc product",
            "items":[
               
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "Type":"Category",
      "Order":1,
      "id":"6",
      "text":"efg",
      "items":[
         {
            "Type":"Product",
            "Order":0,
            "id":2446,
            "text":"efg Product",
            "items":[
               
            ]
         },
         {
            "Type":"Product",
            "Order":0,
            "id":2447,
            "text":"efg1 Product",
            "items":[
               
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
  ]
```

```
    [Serializable]
    public class Item
    {
        public String Type { get; set; }
        public int Order { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
        public IList<Item> items { get; set; }

        public bool ShouldSerializeitems()
        {
            return this.Type != "Product";
        }

        public Item()
        {
            items = new List<Item>();
        }
    }
```

```
    foreach (Products product in products)
    {
                            
       Item product = new Item();
       product.id = Convert.ToInt32(product.GetProductID());
       product.text = product.GetName();
       product.Order = product.GetProductSortOrder();
       product.Type = "Product";
       Category.items.Add(product);
    }
```

Comment: So you *don't* want to modify the JSON string, you want to skip empty arrays

Comment: I want to modify the JSON string by removing "items":[ ] under "Type":"Product".

Comment: Shouldn't it be `return this.Type != "Product";`?

Comment: Yes, let me correct it. I have tried it also earlier.

Comment: I am trying to exclude only public IList<Item> items { get; set; } which corresponds to ShouldSerializeitems

Comment: @Kim - the fix suggested by @NafisIslam works and excludes the `items` list as required, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/5yaRB4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing data from a JSON string post-serialization is nearly always the wrong approach. You should always handle it during serialization.

In addition, you most likely should be checking if items is an empty collection:

```
[Serializable]
public class Item
{
    public String Type { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public IList<Item> items { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldSerializeitems()
    {
        return items.Any();
    }

    public Item()
    {
        items = new List<Item>();
    }
}
```

This correctly outputs:

```
[
  {
    "Type": "Category",
    "Order": 1,
    "id": 24,
    "text": "abc",
    "items": [
      {
        "Type": "Product",
        "Order": 0,
        "id": 1900,
        "text": "abc product"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Type": "Category",
    "Order": 1,
    "id": 6,
    "text": "efg",
    "items": [
      {
        "Type": "Product",
        "Order": 0,
        "id": 2446,
        "text": "efg Product"
      },
      {
        "Type": "Product",
        "Order": 0,
        "id": 2447,
        "text": "efg1 Product"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Hi David, I have tried your solution, still "items":[ ] are included under "Product". Actually, I have copied your Item class and used it in my code to avoid any typos.

Comment: How are you serializing the data? I took your exact json, deserialized it to a list of Item, then re-serialized it and the output worked just fine. If this isn't working for you, you must be doing something else that you haven't highlighted in your question.

Comment: @Kim - are you sure you are using [tag:json.net] and not [tag:system.text.json]?  You have tagged your question [tag:json.net] and this answer will work with that serializer, however if you are using [tag:system.text.json] then conditional serialization is not supported.  If this answer does not work please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68925958/edit) your original question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: dbc, you are correct. I was using System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(categoryData); by mistake. Once I changed it to JsonConvert.SerializeObject(categoryData); it's working fine. Sorry for the oversight on my part!

Comment: David, your solution works fine I was using the wrong serializer. Please see my comment above. Thanks!

Comment: Absolutely do not use that serializer under any circumstances. It is deprecated, slow, and error prone. Glad this works for you with JSON.Net!

Comment: It is better to stop using `JavaScriptSerializer` as it is [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer?view=netframework-4.8#remarks).  It has not been ported to .NET Core, and never will be.