# How to prevent calling a property for the second time, while using the same object inside with "this" clause

Tags: c#, oop, recursion, properties, custom-attributes

I have a class structure which has few string properties, and I want to add another property that returns the `Json` string value of the very same object dynamically.

My problem is, when I use `this` while creating the `Json` result, it calls the object again recursively, and crashes with `StackOverflowException` at the end.

I tried to change `this` field with `New Introducer() { Id = this.Id }` but it caused the same error.

Although I am able to solve it by identifying a bool `IsSerializing` parameter and bypassing the field for the second time manually, I am looking for a more decent solution.

Is there a command or attribute to prevent compiler from calling `Serialized` property for the second time? Or am I calling the property in a wrong way in the first place?

Here is my class:

```
public class Introducer
{
    public Introducer()
    {
        this.Id = 0;
        this.NameSurname = string.Empty;
        this.EmailAddress = string.Empty;
        this.UserCreated = new User();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    private string _NameSurname;
    public string NameSurname { get { return _NameSurname; } set { _NameSurname = value.Trim(); } }
    private string _EmailAddress;
    public string EmailAddress { get { return _EmailAddress; } set { _EmailAddress = value.Trim(); } }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public User UserCreated { get; set; }

    public string Serialized
    {
        get
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this, Formatting.Indented);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps, don't declare the property Serialized as public, just internal.

Comment: [How to exclude property from Json Serialization](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10169648/669576)

Comment: You could add a `[JsonIgnore]` attribute to that property. Or make it a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample to try out. Idea is to use [JsonIgnore](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonIgnoreAttribute.htm) attribute to instruct the serializer to not pick up the property for serialization.

```
class MyClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    private string _NameSurname;
    public string NameSurname { get { return _NameSurname; } set { _NameSurname = value.Trim(); } }
    private string _EmailAddress;
    public string EmailAddress { get { return _EmailAddress; } set { _EmailAddress = value.Trim(); } }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Serialized
    {
        get
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this, Formatting.Indented);
        }
    }
}
```

Invoke as:

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass();
var serialized = obj.Serialized;
```

---

**EDIT:**

Good practice 1: As mentioned in other answers, a `method` could be used instead of the `property` as below:

```
class MyClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    private string _NameSurname;
    public string NameSurname { get { return _NameSurname; } set { _NameSurname = value.Trim(); } }
    private string _EmailAddress;
    public string EmailAddress { get { return _EmailAddress; } set { _EmailAddress = value.Trim(); } }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    public string GetJSON()
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this, Formatting.Indented);
    }
}
```

Good practice 2: Follow the right OOD patterns and let the serialization (or representation) of the object in a format be done in a separate `class`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, I managed to implement the right solution with "JSonIgnore". You are probably right about the "Good practice", however I like "Serialized Version" of it somehow, it gives me the feeling of a "general property" in my code.

Answer (score 2):

You should not put code like that into a property. Properties are intended (conceptually) for data and only an insignificant complexity of code; certainly not recursive code. Serialization is certainly not insignificant code. If you *did* want to have a `Serialized` property that was conceptually appropriate, it should contain a cached version of the serialized object rather than actually generating the serialized data. Instead the functionality for generating the serialized representation of the object should be in a method, not a property.

Comment: I second @BlueMonkMN. Extension function or overriding ToString() are options to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [JsonIgnore]
Or better yet, change this into a method