# Newtonsoft JSON ShouldSerialize and inheritance

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I have a class like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Bar { get; set;}
}
```

This class is used to be stored in a NoSQL database so I need to store the `Bar` value. However, I don't want to expose this value through my API.
So I created a class that inherits from `Foo` that I will return from my API.

I created the method `ShouldSerializeBar` by following the documentation I found [here](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/conditionalproperties.htm).

```
public class Foo2 : Foo
{
    public bool ShouldSerializeBar()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

However, the method is not called. Is there a workaround for this or another way to achieve this?

Comment: Excluding your requirement, did you try it just on `Foo` and did it work?

Comment: Yeah should have mentioned it, it worked when serializing `Foo` directly.

Comment: The reason this doesn't work is because it looks for the method on the declaring type (aka `Foo`), and not any parent/base classes. I don't see another way around it other than the below answers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Bar { get; set;}

    public virtual bool ShouldSerializeBar()
    {
        return true;
    }
}

public class Foo2 : Foo
{
    public override bool ShouldSerializeBar()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. It works but I wanted to avoid adding this method in my base class. Anyway, it will do the trick for now ;)

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to inherit from `Foo` if you use a [IContractResolver](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ContractResolver.htm).

From the docs

> ShouldSerialize can also be set using an IContractResolver.
>   Conditionally serializing a property using an IContractResolver is
>   useful if you don't want to place a ShouldSerialize method on a class
>   or you didn't declare the class and are unable to.

In your case something like this should work.

```
public class ShouldSerializeContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        JsonProperty property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

        if (property.DeclaringType == typeof(Foo) && property.PropertyName == "Bar")
        {
            property.ShouldSerialize = instance => false;
        }

        return property;
    }
}
```

And then you can use it like

```
var foo = new Foo();
foo.Bar = 1;

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo,
        Formatting.Indented,
        new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new ShouldSerializeContractResolver() });
```

Though I don't know if this is more intrusive than the new class (`Foo2`) and the virtual method in its base, at least is another option ;)