# How to skip specific properties when deserializing with newtonsoft json?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, deserialization

I have an API that returns a JSON array with 6000 objects. Each object has around 40 properties, but I only need to use around 20. How do ignore certain properties?
Here is my current code:

```
string json = await client.GetStringAsync(string.Format(url));
List<ListModelClass> ListOfStuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ListModelClass>>(JArray.Parse(json).ToString());

public class ListModelClass {
    public string firstProperty { get; set; }
    public string secondProperty { get; set; }
    public string thirdProperty { get; set; }
    ... about 40 more 
}
```

Comment: Newtonsoft.Json will try and match properties based on name. If the property doesn't exist in your class, it won't be added.

Comment: will the `ScriptIgnore` attribute over the property work?

Comment: @ZacFaragher I thought that, but I wondered if it still did the comparison. I'm trying to reduce the time it takes for the whole operation.

Comment: If that's the case then your source JSON response itself needs to be modified.

Comment: @ZacFaragher That would be the best case, but unfortunately that is not possible.

Comment: Simply not including the unwanted properties in the c# model is almost certainly the fastest way to ignore them given that the JSON cannot be modified.  Though see Erik Lippert's [discussion](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) on this.

Comment: @dbc Thanks I'll go with that then :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to exclude property from Json Serialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169648/how-to-exclude-property-from-json-serialization)

Comment: @james What sort of benchmarking have you already done? Do you know that the time taken is unacceptably long and needs to be reduced or are you doing Premature Optimization? I know it's something that I struggle with too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properties in the JSON object match if and only if there is a property in the model class with the same name or you can use `[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "your_property_name")]`

**So you can only include the properties which you want to use in your model class.**

Comment: Since, I can't change my API, do you just suggest removing the variables from the ModelClass?

Comment: Yes, that's the way you can do it.