# How do I filter the properties in JSON from DTO

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

Below is my DTO.

```
public class CustomerTO
{
  public int Id { get; set;}

  public string Name { get; set;}

  //& so on
}
```

But when I returning the JSON string from my action, I want only few properties to be send to the client.

My Json should look like

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "name": "Ram"
}
```

My Action.

```
public string GetCustomers()
{
  List<CustomerTO> customers = dal.Get();
  var strJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customers);
  return strJson;
}
```

Above action returns string as:-

```
[
{
  "id":1,
  "name":"Ram",
  "age":27,
  "Country":"India"
},
{
  "id":2,
  "name":"Shyam",
  "age":27,
  "Country":"India"
}
]
```

How do I filter the properties in JSON from DTO??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to exclude property from Json Serialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169648/how-to-exclude-property-from-json-serialization)

Comment: @NateBarbettini, I checked using [ScriptIgnore] mentioned in the link but its not filtering

Comment: Use `[JsonIgnore]`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25566387/3191599 (Not sure why that's not the accepted answer on the older question)

Comment: @NateBarbettini, May I know which namespace is required for the [JsonIgnore]

Answer (score 1):

Decorate the members you don't want serialized to the client in your DTO with 
`[JsonIgnore]`

Comment: Which namespace is required for this attribute

Comment: Newtonsoft.Json