# Hide JSON element if certain value instead of null

Tags: c#, json

There is a C# class which has certain properties. When outputting an object of this class in a HttpResponseMessage, I know that if a property is null, we can hide that property in JSON response by annotating that property with the following

```
[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
```

Is there a way to hide the same property if its a certain value? For e.g. dont show SportType property in JSON if its value is "Tennis"?

Comment: Are you using `json.net`?

Comment: Yes.. Newtonsoft json.net

Comment: @bluepiranha Please can you try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169648/how-to-exclude-property-from-json-serialization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `ShouldSerializeX` method to ignore serialization of property depends on some condition.

```
public class SampleJsonClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldSerializeName()
    {
        return (Name != "Tennis");
    }
}
```

Then

```
var list = new List<SampleJsonClass>()
{
    new SampleJsonClass() {Id = 1, Name = "Sample"},
    new SampleJsonClass() {Id = 1, Name = "Tennis"}
};
var serializedJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
```

**Output**

```
[
   {
      "Id":1,
      "Name":"Sample"
   },
   {
      "Id":1
   }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

In `JSON.net` you are be able to use conditional [conditional property serialization](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConditionalProperties.htm)

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Id {get; set;}
    public SomeProperty Name { get; set; }    

    public bool ShouldSerializeSomeProperty()
    {
        return SomeProperty != null || SomeProperty != "Tennis";
    }
}
```

You can define conditional methods for each property you like to define conditional serializing. For example in `ShouldSerializeSomeProperty`, I defined a condition for `SomeProperty` property.