# Json.net serialize only certain properties

Tags: c#, serialization, attributes, json.net

Does Json.net have any way to specify only the properties you want to be serialized? or alternatively serialize certain properties based on binding flags like Declared Only?

Right now I am using `JObject.FromObject(MainObj.SubObj);` to get all properties of SubObj which is an instance of a class that obeys the ISubObject interface:

```
public interface ISubObject
{

}

public class ParentSubObject : ISubObject
{
    public string A { get; set; }
}


public class SubObjectWithOnlyDeclared : ParentSubObject
{
    [JsonInclude] // This is fake, but what I am wishing existed
    public string B { get; set; }

    [JsonInclude] // This is fake, but what I am wishing existed
    public string C { get; set; }
}

public class NormalSubObject: ParentSubObject
{
    public string B { get; set; }
}
```

If `MainObj.SubObj` was a `NormalSubObject` it would serailize both A and B  but if it was `SubObjectWithOnlyDeclared` it would serailize only B and C and ignore the parent property

Comment: `[JsonIgnore]` ?

Comment: Checkout this article on conditional serialization. I found it useful.  https://www.geekytidbits.com/conditional-serialization-with-json-net/

Comment: Also here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59227350/56621

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can write a custom ContractResolver like below

```
public class IgnoreParentPropertiesResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    bool IgnoreBase = false;
    public IgnoreParentPropertiesResolver(bool ignoreBase)
    {
        IgnoreBase = ignoreBase;
    }
    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var allProps = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);
        if (!IgnoreBase) return allProps;

        //Choose the properties you want to serialize/deserialize
        var props = type.GetProperties(~BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy); 

        return allProps.Where(p => props.Any(a => a.Name == p.PropertyName)).ToList();
    }
}
```

---

Now you can use it in your serialization process as:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings() { 
                      ContractResolver = new IgnoreParentPropertiesResolver(true) 
               };
var json1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new SubObjectWithOnlyDeclared(),settings );
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 52):

Rather then having to use `[JsonIgnore]` on every attribtue you don't want to serialise as suggested in another answer.

If you just want to specify properties to serialise, you can do this, using `[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]` and `[JsonProperty]` attributes, like so:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
...
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class Class1
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public string Property1 { set; get; }
    public string Property2 { set; get; }
}
```

Here only `Property1` would be serialised.

Comment: This should be the selected answer

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why @Eser chose to write the answer as comment to your question as opposed to an actual answer... anyway, they're correct.

Apply the `[JsonIgnore]` attribute to any property that you want to ignore.

Comment: This isnt an acceptable answer though, I would need to conditionally ignore `public string A { get; set; }` because in one scenario I dont want it ignored, and in another I do.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a property on your object that is null or the default value, you can let json.net ignore it and NOT serialize it by:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings 
{
    DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
};

JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject, settings);
```

EDIT:

Or global default setting, do this once:

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings 
{
    DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
};
```

Comment: thanks a lot.. this is what I was looking fore