# how to write specific C# property value in json format?

Tags: c#, json, wpf, mvvm

I have some Properties and i want to save some specific property value in json format.Here is my code and i want to save two properties value like SelectedScalesModel and SelectedScales port Can anyone help me with this.

```
public class SetUpViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public List<string> ScalesModel { get; set; } = new List<string> { "None", "METTLER-TOLEDO", "DINI ARGEO DFW-DFWK", "ESSAE SI-810" };
    private string _selectedScalesModel;

    public string SelectedScalesModel
    {
        get { return _selectedScalesModel; }
        set
        {
            _selectedScalesModel = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedScalesModel");
        }
    }

    public List<string> ScalesPort { get; set; } = new List<string> { "None", "COM1", "COM2", "COM3", "COM4", "COM5", "COM6", "COM7", "COM8", "COM9", "COM10", "COM11", "COM12", "COM13", "COM14", "COM15" };
    private string _selectedScalesPort;

    public string SelectedScalesPort
    {
        get { return _selectedScalesPort; }
        set
        {
            _selectedScalesPort = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedScalesPort");
        }
    }
    string _text1;

    public string BlackLineText
    {
        get { return _text1; }
        set
        {
            _text1 = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(BlackLineText));
        }
    }
    public RelayCommand SaveButtonCommand { get; private set; }
    public SetUpViewModel()
    {
        SaveButtonCommand = new RelayCommand(SaveCommand);
    }
    private void SaveCommand()
    {
        SetUpViewModel setUpobj = new SetUpViewModel();
        string strJsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(setUpobj);
        File.WriteAllText("setup.json", strJsonResult);
        MessageBox.Show("File save in Json Format");
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please explain which part of your code has issues? it seems to write json to file.

Comment: @ASh It Doesn't save to Json file as there is a RelayCommand property and i also dont want to save that. I want to save only two property values which is mentioned above

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to exclude property from Json Serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169648/how-to-exclude-property-from-json-serialization)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to `SerializeObject` by anonymous class then carry your expect property instead of `SetUpViewModel` object.

```
private void SaveCommand()
{
    string strJsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
        new {
            SelectedScalesModel = this.SelectedScalesModel,
            SelectedScalesPort = this.SelectedScalesPort
        }
    );
    File.WriteAllText("setup.json", strJsonResult);
    MessageBox.Show("File save in Json Format");
}
```

**Note**

use `this` because your property info in your object.

Comment: That Works Thank you Sir.

Comment: @ShantoSiddiq No problem glad to help