# How to remove an object property from an list/array?

Tags: c#, api, model-view-controller

How can I remove a property from an list/array of a object?

My model contains:

```
 public string FirstName { get; set; }
 public string LastName { get; set; }
 public string Age { get; set; }
 public string Size { get; set; }
```

And i'm converting this to JSON with

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(client);
```

And all works fine... I got all propertys of the object in JSON.

But I need to create two levels of acess, and show all info in one level, and the other level, fewer propertys...

My question is: Can I remove a property of an object?

Someting like this:

```
List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();
//(and this have 100 clients inner)

customer.removeProperty(Age, Size); // Can I have someting like this?
```

Comment: Do you want to remove the property from the model or only from the JSON? If the latter: you can use the attribute `JsonIgnore`([see here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PropertyJsonIgnore.htm))

Comment: check this. Hope it is duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169648/how-to-exclude-property-from-json-serialization

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.scriptignoreattribute?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to exclude property from Json Serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169648/how-to-exclude-property-from-json-serialization)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the json ignore tag above the property. E.g.:

```
[JsonIgnore]
public string Age { get; set; }
```

If you want to be able to serialise both with and without certain properties, without altering the structure of your actual classes, you could try using the example [here](https://blog.rsuter.com/advanced-newtonsoft-json-dynamically-rename-or-ignore-properties-without-changing-the-serialized-class/).

Comment: One question, this wont go ignore in the two cases? (two access)

Comment: Sorry, misread your question, I've edited my answer to include an example of how to do it dynamically without altering the existing classes.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new model with your fewer properties.  Make two lists, one with all the properties and the other with the properties you want removed.

For example

```cs
public YourModelNow
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }
}

public YourModelNowFiltered
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

This is assuming you need two `file.json` with the different properties. If you just need to ignore the properties use Ross Gurburts approach.

Comment: I thought about that :/ but i'm in the deadline day and the real code are really complex with more than 100 propertys... and to populate again all this will gonna be really hard :/

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest using [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/)

you will need to create a DTO [Data Transfer Object] class
which would have the properties that you would like to expose

the usage is pretty simple:

in the config:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
            cfg.CreateMap<YourModel, YourModelDTO>();
        });
```

in the actual usage:

```
IMapper iMapper = config.CreateMapper();
var source = new YourModel();
var destination = iMapper.Map<YourModel, YourModelDTO>(source);
```

for more information and example of what **AutoMapper** could do read [here](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3192900/how-to-work-with-automapper-in-c.html)